# C#: Possible to not implement a protected internal abstract on an abstract class?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, access-modifiers

what do I need to change in my abstract base so that the implementations don't have to implement BOTH methods when only one is needed in any given scenario?  My example is:

```
internal abstract class BaseBar<T> where T : BaseThing
{
    protected internal abstract T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes);
    protected internal abstract T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, string[] fieldNames);
}

class FooBarMapper : BaseBar<FooData>
{
    protected internal override SforceObjectValueData DataObjectFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected internal override FooData DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, string[] fieldNames)
    {
        FooData o = new FooData
        {
            bar1 = bar1,
            bar2 = bar2
        };
        return o;
    }
}
```

Cheers.

edit: The design is weird/bad/stupid I know...I'm working with legacy code and time is not on my side right now for a refactor.  I'm trying to add the second method with the string array.

Comment: I am really a bit iffy on such a design. You would be better off using object composition.

Comment: An internal abstract class?  That means it can only be inherited, and it can only be inherited in FooBarMapper only, nowhere else.  What's the point of that?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Maybe it does not need to be derived from outside that assembly.

Comment: @Robert - It can only be inherited from within the assembly.

Comment: Oh, never mind.  Too early in the morning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make one or both virtual and provide default implementations that calls the other with default parameters (or without passing through the values, depending on which way around you put it).

However, I suspect your design may really require a little more of a rethink because callers will likely have a reference to the base (your abstract class) and won't know they are calling a specific derived version, in which case the calling code should always be free to call which ever method it likes.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this works out for you?

```
internal abstract class BaseBar<T> where T : BaseThing
{
    protected internal abstract T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, params string[] fieldNames);
}
```

Comment: Based off their update this would break any code relying specifically on the method signature. `protected internal abstract T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes)`

Comment: yeah, you'd have to pass `null`

Answer (score 2):

You could also encapsulate the parameters for DataFromXmlElements in a class and then inspect the contents of the class in an elegant way when you write the implementation...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're going to need 2 or 3 abstract classes to achieve this

```
public interface BaseBar1<T> // does one
public interface BaseBar2<T> // does the other
public interface BaseBar3<T> // does both
```

you could use an Optional parameter

```
internal abstract class BaseBar<T> where T : BaseThing
{
    protected internal abstract T DataFromXmlElements(
        IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, string[] fieldNames);
}

class FooBarMapper : BaseBar<FooData>
{
    protected internal override FooData DataFromXmlElements(
        IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, 
        [Optional] string[] fieldNames)
    {
        if (fieldNames == null) // skip stuff
        else // do stuff
    }
```

More on the [Optional Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.optionalattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

An abstract member MUST be implemented, so I guess there is no way around.

Another solution would be to define two interfaces instead, each one containing one of the members to implement. Then the implementing classes can implement one - or both - interfaces.

For example:

```
public interface BaseBarA<T> where T : BaseThing{
  protected internal abstract T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes);  
}

public interface BaseBarB<T> where T : BaseThing{
  T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, string[] fieldNames);  
}
```

Comment: Woops...at the time I wrote this 3 other answers were written. You guys are really fast :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're hoping to do, exactly. What do you expect to happen if the first method gets called? Depending on what you expect, you could make the parent abstract class implement the first method based on the assumption that the second has been implemented:

```
protected internal T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes) {
    return DataFromXmlElements(nodes, null);
}
```

Comment: what's going on here is that I have a base class that handles all kinds of xml formatting and reading from an API.  The method that I'm referring to takes the raw xml and returns me a strongly typed object.  There is a new case where I don't know the fields being returned at design time, and need them at run time.  That's where the field array comes in...but I still want to use the same base class if possible.  It does seem that extracting out lower level XML work into another class would allow this to be more flexible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

You could however have a single abstract internal base class and then two abstracts classes (each with a single abstract method) derived from that.

Finally you would derive the working class from EITHER of the abstracted classes and thus implement the respective single method.

That "would" work but the larger question is "should" you do it? 
I think you may want to reconsider your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Either virtual default implementations as Colin Mackay said, or use interfaces and explicit implementation to stop the methods being called externally.

```
internal interface IBaseBar1<T> where T : BaseThing
{
    T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes);
}

interface IBaseBar2<T> where T : BaseThing
{
    T DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, string[] fieldNames);
}

class FooBarMapper : IBaseBar2<FooData>
{
    FooData IBaseBar2<FooData>.DataFromXmlElements(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, string[] fieldNames)
    {
        FooData o = new FooData
        {
            bar1 = bar1,
            bar2 = bar2
        };
        return o;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. The only option is to rearrange your classes.